# Battery charging slowly on linux | Huawei Matebook X Pro (laptop)

Tags: battery

Three months ago, I bought a Huawei MateBook X pro 2021. I directly installed linux on it, never used W.

Right now, I'm using Kubuntu with kfce which seems to be lighter than Ubuntu and gnome. I've installed TLP to improve my battery life (It can get up to 4-5 hours) while web browsing and using the terminal. Tbh, I'm quite fine with that, but the real problem is that:

**When I use my laptop, it takes many hours to get the laptop charged. I would say around 5 hours to get 80% of the battery charged. And when I watch twitch, or use heavier apps, it get stuck at the same % of battery.**

*Does anyone has any hint to improve the situation?*

You have diverse info below:

```
Specification of my battery:
upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               Sunwoda-
  model:                AP16L5J
  serial:               ####
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              sam. 13 août 2022 23:01:27 (52 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               charging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              19,1764 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         54,4656 Wh
    energy-full-design:  55,2372 Wh
    energy-rate:         11,4829 W
    voltage:             7,777 V
    charge-cycles:       28
    time to full:        3,1 hours
    percentage:          35%
    capacity:            98,603%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-good-charging-symbolic'
  History (charge):
    1660424487  35,000  charging
```

Specification of my laptop:

```
Intel Core i5-1135G7

Mesa Intel Xe Graphics
```

Comment: I'm afraid that has very little to do with Linux (or whichever operating system you are running). The power delivered by the USB ports depends on the hardware. And yes, if it is less than the power actually being used by the phone, it might even keep on discharging. Check this question: [Why is charging from computer using USB slower than using an outlet?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5262/why-is-charging-from-computer-using-usb-slower-than-using-an-outlet)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 

I think I was not clear in my post. I don't charge my phone on my computer. I'm talking about charging my laptop itself. It takes around 5-6 hours to charge my **laptop** up to 80%.

Comment: it is clear, my bad. I'd try to check the hardware first. Like turning on the computer and not letting it go past grub and just leave it there for a couple of hours. Does it charge *a lot* faster? It might depend on what you have connected, a usb keyboard with an intermittent short might use up a lot of energy for example. If your power supply is failing, your computer cannot handle all connected devices or your battery is not in good health, there is very little you can do from the OS, apart from saving energy (as you are doing with TLP, but you should check without it too).

Answer (score 2):

This is not a fix but a bit of a workaround...
I have an Asus c423 Chromebook running Xubuntu with MrChromeBox's UEFI firmware.

I can get full speed charging if I completely shut down the laptop and then plug in the charger.

I can then boot into Xubuntu and retain the high charge rate.

But once Xubuntu is booted if I unplug the charger and plug it back in, the charge rate is back to really slow (I need another shutdown and unplug/plug to get full speed again).

Maybe not necessary, but I wait a few seconds after shutdown before plugging in the charger, and I wait another few seconds after plugging in before booting up.

EDIT: I just discovered that I don't require a full shutdown -- going into deep suspend and then connecting the charger gets me full speed charge that persists when i wake from suspend.